# Beer recommendations?

Tags: discussion, scope

What do you think about questions like [What is the best beer to make for a spouse who prefers sauvignon blanc?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/549/what-is-the-best-beer-to-make-for-a-spouse-who-prefers-sauvignon-blanc) ?

While he's asking for advice on what to brew, it doesn't seem brewing specific- the question is about the same as "What beer should I buy for said spouse?"  I think it's outside the scope of HB.SE- what do you think?

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if it's too subjective. Perhaps a wiki with suggestions would be fine; can there be a right answer?

Comment: I agree it should probably be CW.

Answer (score 3):

I read that question to be soliciting recommendations on styles to try *brewing*, not suggestion on what to pick up at the package store.

The question is asking 'how can I create a beer that has the following characteristics?'

As such, I think it is perfectly appropriate for this site.

Comment: I suppose I could see that argument- I saw it more as "What style beer would a person who likes X like" which doesn't seem on-topic for a brewing site.